# Why can't I use a List containing the parameters to call a method in C#?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to "unroll" parameters to a method/constructor from a List in C# or any language?  Does this kind of feature have a name?

Basically I'm looking to simplify this piece of code:

```
var thick = new List<double>{ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 };
var t = new Thickness(thick[0], thick[1], thick[2], thick[3])
```

I'm specifically asking about the calling code, I'm aware that the framework could change the method declaration to take a  `params double[]`.

And if this is not possible, is it because of type safety concerns?

Comment: I assume thickness is a framework type? If so, just add an extension method to take a list, otherwise you can just modify the type to include a constructor that takes a list.

Comment: How many APIs tend to have multiple parameters of identical types? Outside of "drawing" situations, they tend to lead to confusion because you have to *remember* what each passed value means. Even with your example, I can't think how you'd parameterize thickness over 4 dimensions so I've no idea what this code is doing.

Comment: I can't think of any way to do this without just writing a wrapper - I don't think there are type safety concerns though, just not a feature I suspect they considered useful. If doing `new Thickness(list)` was to be useful then they'd expect the writer of that class to include an appropriate constructor. If the author of the class didn't why would they go to all the effort of making it so you could just pass a list in - its not like it would be easy to do after all and for so little benefit...

Comment: The calling code needs to comply with the method signature. If there are  four double parameters, then that is what the calling code needs to supply. Not aware of any "unrolling" option on the calling side, maybe it is so because it can be solved by modyfiing the method signature to allow params.

Comment: Any problem with just writing a helper method to do that? For instance methods, you can also write an extension method, which then works mostly like any other sealed instance method.

Comment: I'm trying to ask a generic question to improve my C#. The specific API in question was [System.Windows.Thickness](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.thickness(v=vs.110).aspx). I'm very happy with @xanatos answer. And writing an extension method that does the conversion is a good suggestion, too. Thank you to everybody here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. In C# there is no implicit/explicit parameter unrolling, like the javascript [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

There is an explicit parameter "collection" that is the `params` keyword. This must be defined in the method signature, but is probably more similar to the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) array in Javascript. Note that it is only compatible with an array, not a list. The signature must be `params SomeType[] arg`. So to pass a `List<>` you have to `ToArray()` it (I consider it to be a waste of machine space and machine memory).

This feature isn't probably present because C# is strongly typed and a parameter collection would be needed to be checked at runtime (to see if the array length is correct, what types of parameters are used to select an overload and so on).

Using reflection you can use a parameter array. The `Invoke()` method has as one argument an `object[]` that must contain all the parameters.

Quite strangely even using the `dynamic` keyword you can't use a parameter array. This probably because even with `dynamic` the exact number of parameters must be known at compile time, but with a parameter array this wouldn't be known.

Comment: I like the comparison to JS.

Answer (score 1):

I apologise strongly as I have "man flu" atm so my IQ is sub shoesize.

but : you can convert the list to an array and send it to parameters.

```
List<String> s = new List<string>() { "HELLO", "THIS", "IS" };
thing(s.ToArray());

private static void thing(params object[] x)
{
   foreach (object param in x) Console.WriteLine(param);
}
```

Comment: To help out your flu brain this is in the question: "I'm specifically asking about the calling code, I'm aware that the framework could change the method declaration to take a  params double[]" - poor flu brain. :)